# Effects on Early International Travel Ban and Economy

Tags: macroeconomics, covid-19-crisis

Can't find articles regarding on this. Had the country set up an early international travel ban to avoid this Covid-19 pandemic, can that country survive thru local businesses after 4-6 months or more without travel flights? I am thinking that country can survive during this chaotic moment through local business since we are circulating the money within ithe country (assuming there are zero cases of Covid-19 due to early mitigation of the problem). I am not good in economics so please bear with me and if possible use layman's term.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing individual travel with international trade and then later equating travel ban to ban on flights. Also, how do you define country surviving? Arguably, country can survive even nuclear Armageddon if the leadership sits it out somewhere in a bunker and there is some continuity to the government

Comment: @wannabeVeryBest Welcome! Please rephrase the question to make it simpler and more precise.

Comment: What, you mean New Zealand or Australia?